# How do I Target Multiple .Net Frameworks

Tags: blazor

I have a simple Blazor app. I need to include System.Speech as a project reference, which in turn requires targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I edited my project file according to the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks.

The new project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
      https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json;
      https://dotnet.myget.org/F/blazor-dev/api/v3/index.json;
    </RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <Reference Include="System.Speech" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I try to run the project from Visual Studio I get the following errors:

MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.

NETSDK1 The TargetFramework value 'netstandard2.0;net461' is not valid. To multi-target, use the 'TargetFrameworks' property instead.

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Blazor app include .NET 4.6.1 Assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466486/can-a-blazor-app-include-net-4-6-1-assemblies)

Answer (score 0):

If you want client-side blazor, you better use Blazor specific wrapper for Chrome Speech Synthesis API: https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.SpeechSynthesis