# Can a Blazor app include .NET 4.6.1 Assemblies?

Tags: blazor

When I create a Blazor app it targets the .NET Standard 2.0 framework. I want to include System.Speech in a Blazor app. Is it possible to target the .NET 4.6.1 framework in Blazor

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

Right now you can target netstandard2.0 on client-side Blazor, and netcoreapp3.0 on the server.

Hope this helps...